# How update product attributes programmatically?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I use following code to add attributes to a product:

```
foreach ($_attributes as $name => $value) {
        wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $value, $name, true);
        $product_attributes[$name] = array (
            'name' => $name, // set attribute name
            'value' => $value, // set attribute value
            'is_visible' => 0,
            'is_variation' => 1,
            'is_taxonomy' => 1
        );
    }
update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_attributes', $product_attributes );
```

but it remove previous attributes I added in product edit in admin, like product brand or model.
How can I update current product attributes without remove previous ones?

Thanks to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply backup your DB content before updating, like this:

```
$tmpBk = get_post_meta($post_id, '_product_attributes',true);
update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_attributes', array_merge(tmpBk,$product_attributes) );
```

that should be enough to save your previously stored values

Answer (score 0):

I assume you try to save a product attribute assigned to a taxonomy (`'is_taxonomy' => 1` in your code).

### Updating product attributes linked to a taxonomy

If there is a need to update the options of an attribute which has a taxonomy_id set, just saving the product is not enough, unfortunately.

Let's assume you have a product attribute `pa_color`:

```php
object(WC_Product_Attribute)[26022]
  protected 'data' => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => int 5
      'name' => string 'pa_color' (length=8)
      'options' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 185
          1 => int 186
      'position' => int 0
      'visible' => boolean true
      'variation' => boolean true
```

You want to add a third option with the term_id 187. Unfortunately, you have to apply a workaround when just updating the options here.

```php
// retrieve the product
$product = wc_get_product( 3710 );

// get all attributes
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();

// make a copy from the attribute to be updated
$pa_color   = $attributes['pa_color'];

// delete pa_color from the attributes
unset( $attributes['pa_color'] );

// set the attributes without pa_color
$product->set_attributes( $attributes );

// save the product
$product->save();

// set your new options for pa_color
$pa_color->set_options( [ 185, 186, 187 ] );

// add the WC_Product_Attribute object back again
$attributes['pa_color'] = $pa_color;

// set the attributes, now with pa_color in it
$product->set_attributes( $attributes );

// save it again
$product->save();
```

#### Why the workaround?

Setting attributes on a `WC_Product` object in WooCommerce is not recognized by the `changes` attribute in the underlying `WC_Data` class.

By using `$product->save()`, WooCommerce checks if the object has changes or not and creates a `$changeset` in this method. Just setting attribute options, nested too deep in the object, is not recognized by the flat change screening. See code line here in the woocommerce repository:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/319408bb67edc8ea0ab1c6abb04a14b9e65b76ab/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L1441